# read() in Spidermonkey with unicode

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8, spidermonkey

In the Spidermonkey shell, reading in a file with the `read()` function ignores the encoding of the file. Is there any way to read in a UTF-8 or other multi-byte encoded file and preserve the multi-byte characters? Spidermonkey is such a little devil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I talked to the JS guys at Mozilla. Turns out this wasn't entirely possible, so they added a command line flag to enable UTF-8 support for `read()` and `snarf()`.

```
/usr/bin/js -e "print(read('filexyz.txt'))" -U
```

In order to get a copy of Spidermonkey with this addition, you'll have to use the Tracemonkey repository. You can get that with Mercurial:

```
hg clone http://hg.mozilla.org/tracemonkey/
```

Comment: This has changed. `read()` and `snarf()` are now always UTF-8. In fact there is no way to turn it off, so if you have a non-UTF-8 file this can be really annoying. :-P